# is there a Doctrine rollback event? i.e. do stuff to entities on a changelist where there's a rollback

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

working with Doctrine on Symfony 2.6 is there a way to 'detect' a transaction rollback on entities that have been persisted?

**my original problem**: I create new entities which represent files on the filesystem. On `$em->persist()` those entities move files from `/temp` directory to final destiantion vía Doctrine's PrePersist event. If the transaction I'm working on is rolled back later in the code, no rows are created on the database, but the files linger and I have to manually delete them after the `$em->rollback()` with extra code, every time I do this. So I thoguht there might be an event I can use to detect an entity has been 'removed' from the changelist or 'rolledback', so I can delete the entity's related file.

**also**: PostPersist or PostFlush event would seem to solve my problem, but if I have several `$em->flush()` instructions and one that's below in the code throws an exception, and I do `$em->rollback()` on the whole transaction, I still get the lingering files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no rollback event in Doctrine by default. But what you can do, is to extend the Connection class and throw your own event:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Doctrine\DBAL;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Ozean12\ApiSDKBundle\Doctrine\Event\PostCommitEventArgs;
use Ozean12\ApiSDKBundle\Doctrine\Event\PostRollbackEventArgs;

/**
 * Class ConnectionWrapper
 */
class ConnectionWrapper extends Connection
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function commit()
    {
        parent::commit();

        if (!$this->isTransactionActive()) { // to be sure that we are committing a top-level transaction
            $this->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent(PostCommitEventArgs::NAME, new PostCommitEventArgs());
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rollBack()
    {
        parent::rollBack();

        if (!$this->isTransactionActive()) { // to be sure that we are rolling-back a top-level transaction
            $this->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent(PostRollbackEventArgs::NAME, new PostRollbackEventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Then declare this class as a connection wrapper:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    wrapper_class:  Acme\MyBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\ConnectionWrapper
```

And create your event classes and subscriber. You can track the persisted entities in the same subscriber class by listening to the onFlush event so you can perform the actions on them when commit or rollback happens.

Answer (score 2):

For those who comes here: I added PR - Let's hope it will be accepted.

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/4622